# ® (\256) character in C++

Tags: c

What does ® mean in the C language? And in this code, it gives the error "Error: stray '\256'" in the program in the print
part because of ®.

And I want to translate C++ code. While that, I’m taken [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node*' [-fpermissive]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 10
#define EMPTY -1

struct node
{
    char kind;
    char op;
    int number;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct stack
{
    struct node *data[MAX];
    int top;
};

int isempty(struct stack *s)
{
    return (s->top == EMPTY) ? 1 : 0;
}

void emptystack(struct stack* s)
{
    s->top = EMPTY;
}

void push(struct stack* s, struct node *item)
{
    if(s->top == (MAX-1))
    {
        printf("\nSTACK FULL");
    }
    else
    {
        ++s->top;
        s->data[s->top] = item;
    }
}

struct node* pop(struct stack* s)
{
    struct node *ret = NULL;
    if(!isempty(s))
    {
        ret = s->data[s->top];
        --s->top;
    }
    return ret;
}

void postfix2exptree(char* postfix, struct node **root)
{
    struct stack X;
    struct node *newnode, *op1, *op2;
    char numberextract[5];
    char *p;

    emptystack(&X);
    p = &postfix[0];
    strcpy(numberextract, "");
    while(*p)
    {
        while(*p == ' ' || *p == '\t')
        {
            p++;
        }

        if(isdigit(*p))
        {
            while(isdigit(*p))
            {
                strcat(numberextract, p);
                p++;
            }

            newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            newnode->kind = 'N';
            newnode->number = atoi(numberextract);
            newnode->left = NULL;
            newnode->right = NULL;
            push(&X, newnode);
            strcpy(numberextract, "");
        }
        else
        {
            op1 = pop(&X);
            op2 = pop(&X);
            newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            newnode->kind = 'O';
            newnode->op = *p;
            newnode->left = op2;
            newnode->right = op1;
            push(&X, newnode);
        }
        p++;
    }
    *root = pop(&X);
}

int evaluatetree(struct node *x)
{
    if(x->kind == 'O')
    {
        int op1 = evaluatetree(x->left);
        int op2 = evaluatetree(x->right);
        switch (x->op)
        {
           case '+':  return op1 + op2;
           case '-':  return op1 - op2;
           case '*':  return op1 * op2;
           case '/':  return op1 / op2;
           default:   return 0;
        }
   }
   else
       return (x->number);
}

void inorder(struct node *x)
{
    if(x != NULL)
    {
        inorder(x->left);

        if(x->kind == 'O')
            printf("%c ", x->op);
        else
            printf("%d ", x->number);

        inorder(x->right);
    }
}

void preorder(struct node *x)
{
    if(x != NULL)
    {
        if(x->kind == 'O')
            printf("%c ", x->op);
        else
            printf("%d ", x->number);

        preorder(x->left);
        preorder(x->right);
    }
}

void postorder(struct node *x)
{
    if(x != NULL)
    {
        postorder(x->left);
        postorder(x->right);

        if(x->kind == 'O')
            printf("%c ", x->op);
        else
            printf("%d ", x->number);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *r;
    postfix2exptree("100 50 - 2 /", &r);
    printf("Inorder = ");
    *inorder®;
    printf("\nPreorder = ");
    preorder®;
    printf("\nPostprder = ");
    postorder®;
    printf("\nResult = %d\n", evaluatetree®);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ® character doesn't mean anything in C. If at all legal it would be just another character like the letter A but your code looks funky, this line near the bottom: `*inorder®;`, that's not legal C. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Good. So ® here was inserted instead of `(r)` when someone grabbed this code from a blog post on a platform that performs automatic replacement of certain character combinations by non-keyboard symbols.

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov: The link is (effectively) broken now (domain taken over by some gambling entity)

Comment: 256 (octal) = 174 (decimal) = 0xAE (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 3):

This is an artefact of "smart" text editors.

The code is supposed to read:

```
inorder(r);
printf("\nPreorder = ");
preorder(r);
```

where `r` is a `struct node *`.

The original author pasted the text and didn't check, smart text editing transformed (r) into the copyright sign.

Note that `inorder` and `preorder` are functions defined earlier in the code.

Comment: Nit: ® U+00AE is [registered trademark symbol/sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol) not [copyright symbol/sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_symbol) © U+00A9 which similarly but not the same is often written (c).

Comment: There is a similar Stack Overflow question where a variable name happens to be `reg` and in a code line, `... &reg;` is interpreted by a text editor as the [HTML character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) `&reg;`... (also codepoint U+00AE) and converted to "®".

Comment: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*